# Server Side validation not working on MVC partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a partial view that's added to the main view via ajax call, triggered by the user clicking a button (the user clicks a button, and the partial view is added to the page).

The partial view is strongly typed to a different model than the main page.  In my main page, I display the validation errors at the top, and then also have the message displayed below each field.  The validation errors for my partial view are displaying at the top of the page, but they are not displaying with the field itself.

Field from partial view:

```
                    <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmploymentCompany, "* Employer Name")
                    <input type="text" name="TempEmployments[@idx].EmploymentCompany" class="field panel-field" maxlength="40" style="width: 250px !important;" value="@EmploymentCompany"/>
                    @Html.ValidationMessage("EmploymentCompany")
                </td>
```

Rendered as:

```
<td>
<label for="EmploymentCompany">* Employer Name</label>
<input type="text" name="TempEmployments[0].EmploymentCompany" class="field panel-field" maxlength="40" style="width: 250px !important;">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="EmploymentCompany" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
<td>
```

In the controller, where validation is called:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Applicant application)
    { 
       this.ModelState.AddModelErrors(application.Validate(update: false));
       //if valid, other stuff is done.  otherwise:
       return View(application);
    }
```

In the main view, where validation errors are displayed at the top:

```
if (!this.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
<div class="validation-summary-errors" data-valmsg-summary="true">
    <ul>
        @foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
        {
            foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors)
            {
                <li>@Html.Raw(error.ErrorMessage)</li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
</div>
}
```

And in the entity where validation errors are added:

```
foreach (var job in TempEmployments)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(job.EmploymentCompany))
                {
                    errorDictionary.Add("EmploymentCompany", "Company Name is required");
                }
}
```

And here is what the errors look like at the top of the page:
[image: error msg]

And the partial view:

[image: partial view]